# Need help on Error ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc'

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, utf-8, decode

I can't really find where i where i messed up.
that's probably due too my programming skills.
So i hope some can help me pointing out where i should where i need to decode or endcode.. or whatever?
to stop having Error: ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc'.

The code works fine, till it hits some specific code in the website tekst it can't read or decode.
i did wright various articles on this website about sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') but is still don't get it too work. So some help on where i need too put what would be helpful.

```
# import requests
import datetime
from time import sleep, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from itertools import repeat


def run_process(page_number):
    page_number += 1
    base_url = f'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/p{page_number}'
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    jsonStr = soup.find('script', {'id':'page-data'}).text
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)


    df = json_normalize(jsonData['properties'])
    root_URL = 'https://jaap.nl'
    df['detailsUrl'] = root_URL + df['detailsUrl']

    allPropDetails = pd.DataFrame()


    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        propDetails = pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
        w=1
        detailLink = row['detailsUrl']
        print ('Scraping: %s' %(row['location.street']))
        dfs = pd.read_html(detailLink)

        for each in dfs:

            #each = dfs[8]
            w=1
            if each.isnull().all().all():
                continue
            each = each.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

            specialCase = False
            for col in list(each.columns):
                if each[col].dtypes == 'object':
                    if each[col].str.contains('Voorziening').any():
                        specialCase = True
                        break

            if specialCase == True:
                df_obj = each.select_dtypes(['object'])
                each[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('. '))
                cols1 = list(each.iloc[2:,0])
                each = each.iloc[2:,:]
                each[1] = each[1] + '---' + each[2]
                each = each.iloc[:,-2]
                each.index = cols1

                each = each.to_frame().T
                propRow = each
                propRow.index = [0]

                temp_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
                for col in propRow.columns:
                    temp_df = temp_df.merge(propRow[col].str.split('---', expand=True).rename(columns={0:col, 1:col+'.distance'}),left_index=True, right_index=True )
                propRow = temp_df


            else:
                df_obj = each.select_dtypes(['object'])
                each[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('. '))

                temp_df = each.T
                cols = [ temp_df.index[0] + '_' + colName for colName in list(temp_df.iloc[0,:]) ]

                propRow = temp_df.iloc[-1,:]
                propRow.index = cols
                propRow = propRow.to_frame().T
                propRow.index = [0]

            propDetails = propDetails.merge(propRow, left_index=True, right_index=True)


        propDetails.index = [idx]    
        allPropDetails = allPropDetails.append(propDetails, sort=True)
    
    page_number += 1
    df = df.merge(allPropDetails, how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)        
    return df
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set variables
    start_time = time()
    current_page = 1
    output_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    output_filename = f'C:/Users/907133/Pythonstuff/output_{output_timestamp}.csv'
    
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    while current_page <= 180:
        print(f'Scraping page #{current_page}...')
        df = run_process(current_page)
        final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
        current_page = current_page + 1
    final_df.to_csv(output_filename, index=False)
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f'Elapsed run time: {elapsed_time} seconds')
```

Comment: If the error says "can't encode", then it's not about reading, but writing. The traceback tells you at which line your code fails. It might well be a print statement. If you can't get your terminal/IDE/notebook to use UTF-8, you might want to resort to writing to a file rather than printing to STDOUT.

Comment: ASCII has just 128 characters (including control symbols), so just characters from 0 to 127. Your character is clearly not ASCII. Trick: do not `print`. Write to a log file (and open it as UTF-8).

Comment: Oke thanks!, Can you give a example how would you do that in the case above? or some article that explains it?